# Php Check-in feature like foursquare

Tags: php, checkin

How does one go on making a system like the **check-in feature like foursquare in php?**

I would like to build a feature like this but i don't know how to start it (just the check-in feature). Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach it would be to have Users, Locations, and check-ins SQL tables and set up foreign keys in the check-ins table. Anytime someone checks in at a location you can add an entry to that table.

Obviously the architecture would be different on a scale like foursquare. You'd want to use NoSQL or something like it (JSON, MongoDB) with the same "check-ins table" approach, but built for faster traversing.

Comment: Thank you for you response that's how i was thinking on how to go with it. I want to use this for my site and soon use it in an app.

Comment: Just a small note, INNER JOIN != JOIN